# Segment fault when creating PyList_New in Python C extention

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, python-c-api

parser.cpp:

```
#include <python3.4/Python.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
    PyObject* test(const char* filename)
    {
        size_t LIM = 1000;
        PyObject* result = PyList_New(LIM);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < LIM; i++) {
            PyObject * t = PyList_New(0);
            PyList_Append(t, PyLong_FromLong(1));
            cout << i << "/" << PyList_Size(result) << " " << t << endl;
            if (PyList_SetItem(result, i, t) != 0) {
                cout << "!" << endl;
            }
        }
        Py_INCREF(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

compiles by:

```
g++ -O2 -fPIC -std=c++11 -shared -o parser_c.so parser_c.cpp -lpython3.4m
```

test.py:

```
import ctypes
import datetime
p = ctypes.CDLL('./parser_c.so')
p.test.restype = ctypes.py_object
print(p.test("asd"))
```

Executing python3 test.py is terminated with segmentation error and the last line I've got by debug output is

```
381/1000 0x7f0996bb5a88
```

Besides, it's works properly if I don't import datetime in test.py or decrease LIM in parser.cpp.

I can't figure out why that happends.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you import `datetime` before `ctypes`, it works too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that ctypes releases the global interpreter lock and so calls to Python api functions are undefined

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

> The Python global interpreter lock is released before calling any function exported by these libraries, and reacquired afterwards.

You need to re-acquire it at the start of your function, and re-release it at the end:

```cpp
PyObject* test(const char* filename)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    // The bulk of your code stays the same and goes here ...

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);

    return result;
}
```